# Elasticsearch php client date range not working

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm using the official PHP client from here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/index.html

Everything works fine but one thing - filter by date range;
The field type in mapping is Date, but I do not getting filtered result.
Query structure looks like this and it works fine when I'm executing in Sense chrome plugin:

```
{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "filter": {
            "range": {
                "myfield": {
                    "gt": "2015-01-10"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

mapping for field:

```
"myfield": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "dateOptionalTime"
           }
```

In php client I've tried to check range filter with another field which is not datetype and it works fine, the only problem with datetype fields.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me. According the documentation, it should work, but not for me. You didn't post your mapping file, but code below works for me.

Use from instead of gt.

Example:

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "range": {
               "myfield": {
                  "from": "2015-01-10"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Added mapping for a field in question, thanks for response but it also failed

Comment: Problem solved by following steps: when you try to use 'or' filter and filter one type by range, it takes into account same field type from another index types included in 'or' condition, so same field types were different in different types, I've updated mapping to make field types same, and used raw json query method for php client